# Securing Spring Boot with vaadin

Tags: spring-security, vaadin

Instead of using InMemory Auth I am trying to authenticate with BD user, so a created class user and roles, and added this code to this class

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetails customUserDetails;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Set default security policy that permits Vaadin internal requests and
        // denies all other
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, "/logout");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}userpass").roles("USER");
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetails).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider createDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetails);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }
}
```

But when i try to authenticate it does not accept

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this, but usually it goes roughly like this. The relevant pieces, the complete solution is too lengthy for SO. There should not be anything Vaadin specific, but just follow Spring documentation on the matter.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig (UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
    ...
}
```

And then implement `UserDetailsService` according to Spring spec.

```
@Service
@Primary
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository; // or what ever you have named it ...

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // implement this according to your actual implementation of user database
    }

}
```